# Inverse function theorem: domain is subset of the image

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the inverse function theorem to get the result that $F(U)\cap U$ is clopen in $U$. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z\in \text{cl}_U(F(U)\cap U)$ then there is a sequence $(y_n)\subseteq  F(U)\cap U$ such that $y_n\to z$. And $y_n=F(x_n)$ for some $(x_n)\subseteq U.$ So, $z=\underset{n\to \infty}\lim F(x_n)$. Now, by compactness of the closed ball $\overline U$,  there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which we still call $(x_n)$, such that $x_n\to b\in \overline U$. It follows from the continuity of $F$ that $z=F(b)$, which by hypothesis means that $b\notin \partial U$ (because $z\in U$ and $F$ maps $\partial U$ to $U^c).$ It follows that $z\in F(U)\cap U$, so $F(U)\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

On the other hand, if $z\in F(U)\cap U$ then $z=F(x)$ for some $x\in U$ and the inverse function theorem gives us open sets $x\in V\subseteq  \mathbb R^2$ and $F(x)=z\in W\subseteq  \mathbb R^2$ such that $F(V)=W$. We may assume that $V\subseteq U.$ The set $W\cap U\subseteq F(U)\cap U$ is open in $U$ and contains $z$ so $F(U)\cap U$ is open in $U$.